# getting validation into a style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation, xaml

I use IDataErrorInfo on my viewmodels and I have a style (below) for a TextBox with an error template that works ok. I know that "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" used like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

will force WPF to use IDataErrorInfo but am wondering how to get that baked into my style.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    ...

    <!--
    Error handling
    -->
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text=" *" 
                               Foreground="Red" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
                               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red"  BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="placeholder"></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to be able to be able to use the `ValidatesOnDataError=True` in your style, that so you don't have to repeat it every time.

If that's the case you can't, because that is a property of the data binding and not the style; and you can't template the data binding.

Comment: yeah that is my motivation. Seems like there should be an aid for the incredibly lazy somewhere,

Answer (score 1):

I just wonder if you use a Label instead of a TextBox, then in the style of the Label you can probably do something like this,

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:Label">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
```

Comment: Nice thought! Did you get a chance to try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because that is part of the definition of the binding to your property, not how the error is visualized.